# Return two dimentional array of all the pairwise products

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

Write a method `static int [][] pr (int [] v)` that returns a 2D array consisting of all the pairwise products
of the elements of v. E.g., for `a = {{2, 3, 1}` the method returns 2D array `b = {{4, 6, 2}, {6, 9, 3}, {2, 3, 1}}`. Please note: This is an 2010 exam question, taken from Software and Programming 1 module.

```
public class ETenBTwoD
{
    public static int [] [] pr (int [] v)
    {
        int [] a = {2, 3, 1};
        int [][] b = {{0, 0, 0},{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}};
        for (int i = 0; i<a.length; i++)
        {
            a[i] = a[i] * a[i];
        }
        return a;
    }
}
```

I am not sure how to do this. Help will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: @OliCharlesworth you are being harsh - there is a piece of code (even if it does not match the requirement)!

Comment: I have created the array and 2 dimentional array  which is b with empty values. If I can do  pairwise products and place the answer in the 2 dimentional array [][] b. That should solve the problem.

Comment: Hint: You will need a nested loop.

Comment: Hint: You won't be able to specify / create the array size at compile-time. You need to do a run-time calculation of the input array size to determine the size of the output array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key is to use a nested loop.  As you can see v[i] takes the first number (choosen by the first loop) and multiplies it by all the numbers in v (parameter array) since j has to increment the full length of v.  The first loop then picks out the second number and the second loop does it again.  In b[i][j] the i represents the current number we are calculating pairwise products for.

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    int[] v = {5,4,3,2,1};
    pr(v);}
    public static int [] [] pr (int [] v)
    {
        int [][] b =new int[v.length][v.length] ;
        for (int i = 0; i<v.length; i++)
        {
            for(int j=0; j<v.length;j++){
                b[i][j] = v[i] * v[j];
            }
        }

        System.out.println(b[0][0]+" "+b[0][1]+" "+b[0][2]);
        System.out.println(b[1][0]+" "+b[1][1]+" "+b[1][2]);
        System.out.println(b[2][0]+" "+b[2][1]+" "+b[2][2]);
        return b;
    }
```

Comment: This doesn't solve the variable-sized input array issue however. The example of the 3-element input array is just an example.

Comment: This is not very didactic and it doesn't help very much in understanding why the original approach does not work...

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't not paying attention to the full question.  its...not very difficult to understand a nested loop, but I will try to explain.

Comment: It makes sense Youssef. i is outter loop at position 0 and j is inner loop position at 0. j[0] X i[0], and inner loop gets incremented, once the inner loop is complete, outer loop gets incremented by 1 and goes inside inner loop again. Same thing happens on third time. Even the System.out.println explains, how it gets incremented.